# Inserting a Row Hash in a H2 database

Tags: h2, liquibase

I would like to configure a H2 database, that for every saved record a hash value is calculated. The Hash should contain all columns of the table.

**Example:**

There is this table user:

id | name | age | hash

and a user John with an age of 45 would be added.
The database should create this record:

1 | John | 45 | hash(1, john, 45)

Is it possible to create this setup in for a H2 database within a liquibase changelog?

I thought about it might work with *valueComputed* and the H2 *hash* function (http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#hash).

Comment: Does [this link](https://groups.google.com/g/h2-database/c/bHP8w6N-5xs) help you?

Comment: The function CALL HASH('SHA256', STRINGTOUTF8('sha256'), 1) is helping me. I can execute this function from the H2 web console, but not from withing the liquiubase changelog.

Comment: As you mentioned, `valueComputed` should help. Did you give it a try?

Comment: I could not figure out how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with H2, but whether you are using xml, json, or yaml (or formatted sql of course) you can always write custom sql to take advantage of dbms-specific sql syntax:

xml Example using the Oracle-specific to_date function:

```
<sql>
  insert into table1 values (id, start_time)
  values (1, to_date('05/03/2021 13:00:00','mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss'));
</sql>
```

Comment: I would like to encapsulate the logic into the changelog.